Unwanted URL segment appearing on Google search console
I have a website with localized language pages (e.g., /hindi, /tamil), but some URLs are being crawled with an extra language segment (e.g., /hindi/gujarati/blog/asian-paints-share-q2-results). These URLs were not created by us and are being crawled but not indexed. How can I resolve this issue to ensure that only the correct URLs are indexed by search engines?

Crawlers might have outdated information about your website. Please make sure you have an updated sitemap.xml available (upload to Google Search Console if possible).

Ensure proper URL structure using canonical tags and fix URL parameters. Example: IndeedJobsOfficial uses hreflang tags to manage language-specific pages efficiently.
